# How to display certain table schema columns in a datagridview control using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, schema, sqldatatypes

I have a method that displays the entire schema of an MS Access table into a datagridview control. How would I be able to display just the column name and data type schema columns in the datagridview. The method that I am working with is below. Thank you for any advice.

```
private void ButtonFieldHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char ch = '"';

    dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
    dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    DataTable data; 
    OleDbDataReader reader; 

    dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ch + this.stringData + ch;
    dbConn.Open();
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + this.comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader(); 

    foreach (DataRow tableField in data.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn tableProperty in data.Columns)
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
    this.txtRecords.Text = data.Rows.Count.ToString();

    reader.Close();
    dbConn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code modified to work as you need using OleDbDataAdapter:

```
 private void ButtonFieldHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = '"';

        var dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
        var dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataReader reader;

        dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ch + this.stringData + ch;
        dbConn.Open();
        dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
        dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + this.comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCmd);
        adapter.Fill(data);


        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnType");

        foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType.ToString());
        }

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

        this.txtRecords.Text = data.Rows.Count.ToString();

        dbConn.Close();
    }
```